# React Hooks: Set All State Values to the Same Values with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

New to React. I am trying to figure out how to set the state values of all objects with the values of a one specific object.

Here is the CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-https-1o415

If you click on the `Apply to All` button in the `Fork` section, the data in `Spoon` and `Knife` would be updated to be the same as that in the `Fork` section. Is it possible to set the data of one object in the map, with that of another object? Would it happen in the map function or somewhere else? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [kitchenItems, setkitchenItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("./data.json")
      .then((response) => setkitchenItems(response.data.kitchen));
  }, []);

  function applyAll(i) {
    const updatedData = kitchenItems.map((item, idx) => {
      if (idx === i) {
        return {
          ...item,
          size: item.size,
          text: item.text,
          value: item.value
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setkitchenItems(updatedData);
    console.log(kitchenItems);
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {kitchenItems.map((item, i) => (
        <div className="utensil" key={i}>
          <h2>{item.name}</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>{item.size}</li>
            <li>{item.text}</li>
            <li>{item.value}</li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" name="apply" onClick={() => applyAll(i)}>
            Apply to All
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66159372/1264804), you will not see the update with the console log, since it would be an asynchronous and you would need to use a useEffect to see the update. You are close on your code though. Couple things:

1. You need to use a stable function for the applyAll (useCallback hook)
2. You were looking at index equal to the object you are trying to copy, and just using it's same values. This only changed spoon into an already spoon for it's values of size and more. What you wanted was to change the others. Here is an example I made on your codepen:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [kitchenItems, setkitchenItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("./data.json")
      .then((response) => setkitchenItems(response.data.kitchen));
  }, []);

  const applyAll = useCallback((i) => {
    const updatedData = kitchenItems.map((item, idx) => {
      if (idx !== i) { //<-- You want to check if the index of the item doesn't equal the index of the item you want to change it to.
        return {
          ...item,
          size: kitchenItems[i].size, //<-- Since you have the index of the item, you can just call to get it's values here from kitchenItems
          text: kitchenItems[i].text,
          value: kitchenItems[i].value
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setkitchenItems(updatedData);
  }, [kitchenItems]);

  return (
    <main>
      {kitchenItems.map((item, i) => (
        <div className="utensil" key={i}>
          <h2>{item.name}</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>{item.size}</li>
            <li>{item.text}</li>
            <li>{item.value}</li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" name="apply" onClick={() => applyAll(i)}>
            Apply to All
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`setkitchenItems()` is the asynchronous method, and you can't get the updated value of `kitchenItems` immediately after `setkitchenItems()`.

```
    setkitchenItems(updatedData);
    console.log(kitchenItems); // This will console the old `kitchenItems`
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding `kitchenItems` dependency to check updated state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(kitchenItems);
}, [kitchenItems]);
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I've updated the CodeSanbox. What I'm trying to figure out is if I can set the values of all the objects in kitchenitems to values of the kitchenItem that I've clicked on.